# why my code is returning Boolean rather than showing the elements of the list when filtering based on date?

Tags: flutter, datetime, filtering

I'm having a problem with filtering a list based on the last 2 days,the condition seems right when I run the code and hit the filter button but it return boolean rather than showing the elements in the list itself and i don't know why.Thanks in advance for any help.

[this is an example of what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyMu1.png)

problem is here when i use reusable button to filter the list when click, it tests the condition of filter if it's right or not and return a boolean without filtering the list itself and return the filtered items in the list i'm not sure of 'now_2days.isBefore' statement if it's correct and i also think it's the reason behind the boolean value but i don't know what to use instead

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   List<listCard> orderWidgets;

   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       elevation: 0.0,
       bottomOpacity: 0.0,
     ),
     drawer: AppDrawer(),
     body:
     Column(
       children: [
         Row(children: [
           Container(
             child: Expanded(
               child: ReusableTestChip(
                 onPress: () {
                   setState(() {

                     // here is the filter ;

                     filteredListbyDate.addAll(orderWidgets.where((element) {
                       final date = element.date;
                       var dateTime1 = DateTime.parse(date);
                       print(dateTime1);
                       print(now_2days.isBefore(dateTime1));
                       return now_2days.isBefore(dateTime1);

                     }).toList());
                   });
                 },
                 cardChild: Text(
                   'Filter by last 2days',
                   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                   style: TextStyle(
                     color: selectedButton == Btn.last2day
                         ? KWhiteColor
                         : KInActiveColor,
                     fontSize: 25.0,
                     fontFamily: 'Cairo-Italic',
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                   ),
                 ),
                 colour:
                     selectedButton == Btn.last2day ? KInActiveColor : KWhiteColor,
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ]),
     
`here is the stream where the list being filled using listcard as template then inserted into the Column`

           StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
           stream: _firestore.collection('visithomeorders').snapshots(),
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if (!snapshot.hasData) {
               return Center(
                 child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                   backgroundColor: KInActiveColor,
                 ),
               );
             }
             final orders = snapshot.data.docs;
              orderWidgets = [];
             for (var order in orders) {
               final orderName = order.data()['name'];
               final orderAddress = order.data()['address'];
               final orderTime = order.data()['time'];
               final orderDate = order.data()['date'];
               final ordermobile1 = order.data()['mobile1'];
               final ordermobile2 = order.data()['mobile2'];
               final orderphone = order.data()['phone'];
               final ordertests = order.data()['tests'];
               final orderlat = order.data()['lat'];
               final orderlong = order.data()['long'];

               final orderWidgetshape = listCard(
                 name: orderName ?? 'default value',
                 location: orderAddress ?? 'default value',
                 time: orderTime ?? 'default value',
                 date: orderDate ?? 'default value',
                 colour: KInActiveColor ?? 'default value',
                 mobile1: ordermobile1 ?? 'default value',
                 mobile2: ordermobile2 ?? 'default value',
                 phone: orderphone ?? 'default value',
                 tests: ordertests ?? 'default value',
                 lat: orderlat ?? 'default value',
                 long: orderlong ?? 'default value',
               );
               orderWidgets.add(orderWidgetshape);
             }
             return Column(
               children: orderWidgets,
             );
           },
         ),
       ],
     ),
     bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomBar(),
   );
 }
}
```

[declared variables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Csw.png)

[a screenshot for the list on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEGf0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'where` method compares the entries and returns true\false for this comparison. By using `.toList()` at the end as it is now in your code, you return the results of `true\false`. now_2days returns a boolean, so I'm assuming you want to return the values where this whole logic results in true.

I would go for this:

```
 filteredListbyDate = orderWidgets.where((element) => now_2days.isBefore(DateTime.parse(element.date))).toList();
```

Also, change this part of your code:

```
);
orderWidgets.add(orderWidgetshape);
}
filteredListbyDate = orderWidgets;
return Column(
children: filteredListbyDate,
```

Comment: it gave me an error when run the code => Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
                     print(filteredListbyDate.addAll(orderWidgets.where((element) => now_2days.isBefore(DateTime.parse(element.date)) == true).toList()));

Comment: Why are you printing it?

Comment: i tried to delete the " filteredListbyDate.addAll() " part and run the code it didn't return any error but the list remain the same i mean the filter didn't filter the list and return the items base on the filtering condition

Comment: try removing the `==true` part.

Comment: nothing changed, i declared now_2days right after the import of libraries part

Comment: would you please check the images above, i added some to make it more clear for you

Comment: Where are you using `filteredListbyDate`? I edited my code in the answer.

Comment: i didn't use it anywhere in the code before, when i saw the (orderWidgets.where .... ) didn't work for me i thought maybe putting the result inside a list would make a difference !

Comment: Edited answer again, please copy both codes posted, and make them exactly as in the answer and try.

Comment: it worked when i added this part to the code with beside your changes to it, thanks in a million for your help.

void initState() {
    super.initState();
      setState(() {
        filteredListbyDate = orderWidgets;
      });
  }

Comment: You're most welcome! :) 
Kindly consider marking it as an answer if it helped you out.